# error in displaying detail from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a3629462/public_html/delete/single ad display.php on line 29
```

this the error am getting and this the part am getting error

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

the exact error line is

```
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

full code

```
<?php
    $host = ""; // Host name 
    $username = ""; // Mysql username 
    $password = ""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name = "a3629462_sell"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "forum_question"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
```

full code of the error shown is added

Comment: `$tbl_name` is undefined (no where to be found)

Comment: can you show some more code , like what is the value of $tbl_name

Comment: What is output of `echo $sql;`?

Comment: Try to use `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` instead of `mysql_query($sql)` you will got some clue.

Comment: You are either not connected to MySQL (or to a database), or your query has a syntax error or is referring to a non existing table or field, mysql_query returning false instead of a resource.

Comment: it works now, i had error in table name thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

try this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$tbl_name."` WHERE id = ' ". $id ." '") or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the following:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `" . $tbl_name . "` WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
```

If it still won't work, try to

```
echo $sql;
```

and run it directly in your database to see if it succeeds, or gives a more detailed error.